# "It {has been raining} and the streets were wet." Is the textbook wrong?

Tags: exam-questions, perfect-constructions, perfect-continuous

[image: screenshot of the question transcribed below]

In my exercise book, I have a question as follows:

> 15. It_____and the streets were wet.
>     A. has been raining
>     B. rains
>     C. has rained
>     D. would rain

The answer is A and I don't know why it has to be A. I think it looks strange to me as either the present perfect or the present perfect continuous suggests an event that is related to PRESENT. I think the question itself has some problem. 'The streets were wet', the predicate is 'were', suggesting this is a fact that happened in the past and has nothing to do with present, but why it uses a perfect continuous tense?

Comment: It is a bad question. The answer should be ***had* been raining**. Your reasoning is correct, that it does not relate to the present. You could also write a different sentence using **would**: *In that part of the country it would rain for weeks on end, and the streets were always wet.*

Answer (score 1):

It had rained and the streets were wet.

This is the correct answer. 'Been' is assigned to 'passive voice' exclusively. If the verb is transitive then we can use the passive voice.

The food had been eaten and the table was dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Overally, two dependent clauses must be of the same tense. 
Your reasoning is true. 
If we want to say 'the streets were wet' we must in main clause say: It had been rained and the streets were wet.

The match between the clauses in terms of tense must be done.

It had been raining is also false, because 'raining' is suggesting the progressive aspect (ongoing action by -ing ) while the perfect aspect 'rained' is required to suggst a complete action.

Comment: If you want to add more information you can [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/183253/edit) your other answer instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: You might want to use:subject, verb, object.